# Cannot resolve symbol 'FirestoreRecyclerAdapter' in android studio

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore, firebaseui

I am developing an android app that fetches the documents from a collection and for this, I am trying to use the firestore recycler adapter but I am getting error "Cannot resolve symbol 'FirestoreRecyclerAdapter'"

Same error for FirestoreRecyclerOptions
[image: error]

[image: error sample]

I have also added the dependency in app level build.gradle file as

```
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-firestore:6.4.0'
```

Also tried invalidating and clearing the cache of android studio and doing multiple grade syncs still, the errors persist

Here what I think the error could be is that the library is not properly installed but then why only this library other all firebase libraries are getting installed perfectly fine

**Also important point the same library is working for different android project**

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Do you have the proper import for `FirestoreRecyclerAdapter`?

Comment: used this as import com.firebase.ui.firestore.FirestoreRecyclerAdapter; which is correct i guess as it is working for other android projects

Answer (score 1):

1. Acc. to [docs](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/firestore/README.md) it is not FirestoreRecyclerAdapter it is  FirestoreRecyclerOptions
2. try with latest dependency

   ```
       implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-firestore:8.0.0'
   ```

Comment: same error for FirestoreRecyclerOptions see i have updated the question